# BIOS update failed on Asus ROG Strix B 450 F Gaming MB

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I updated by BIOS today and it messed up my whole system. The update was not interrupted in any way and it went through ok.
After the restart though, my PC fails to boot.
I tried repairing it from a recovery disk, it failed. I tried reinstalling windows, it failed and now I have multiple windows instances that I think might conflict with one another.
Also, BIOS doesn't seem to recognize the correct bootable disk.

Also, when I try changing the RAM frequency to the correct one, it fails start the PC several times and then goes straight to BIOS for a default config.

I tried executing these commands:
bootrec /FixMBR
bootrec /FixBoot - Access denied here

Haven't reached these ones yet, because the above is erroring out.
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd

Any help is much appreciated.